# Manhwa in which the female lead is reborn in the world of a book as an evil aunt who is destined to die at the hands of her nephew

Tags: story-identification, manga, reincarnation

I the read this manhwa when I was younger and can't remember the name and would love to re-read it.

The manhwa is about the female lead who is reborn as a character from a book that she had read in her previous life. She was reincarnated as the evil aunt whose destined to die by her nephew (the male lead) when he gets older and she wants change the ending by befriending her nephew.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this? Also, do you recall the hair colour of the female lead?

Comment: Are there any other details you can remember? Reincarnating as an evil character that is related to the main characters of the original story is an extremely common setup in manhwa. And being nice to the main characters is usually how they try to survive. Do you remember any details like the aunt/nephew's age or appearance, any other characters, the circumstances of their life, or the specific ways the aunt tries to be nice to the nephew?

Comment: For example, are the aunt and nephew both blonde, living in a village, until a black-haired duke (the male lead of the manhwa) comes to pick up her nephew because he's secretly nobility? Just a wild guess - in that particular story I don't believe the aunt dies to the nephew.

Comment: Hi qazmlpok, your example is actually pretty much how the start of the story goes  unfortunately I don't really remember much as it was such a long time ago. I can't remember hair colour or names or if the man that come to collect his nephew was a duke but I do believe the nephew was nobility or something similar. Sorry I'm not much help

Comment: @Raiwen - In roughly which year did you read this? I believe qazmlpok was referring to _The Villainess Flips the Script_, but that was only published in 2021.

Comment: I remember reading it around the time I was in college or just after. My college years were in-between 2012-2016. Unfortunately as was said above this story isn't very original.

Comment: Perhaps not original any more, but if it's from around or before 2016 it might have been one of the popularizing stories. There weren't nearly as many webtoons back in 2016 so that should narrow things down a lot.

Comment: Any chance the protagonist isn't the kid's aunt, but his (much) older sister instead? The initial setup is similar to "The villainess flips the script" - younger brother of protagonist discovers he's royalty, forces sister to go along with him. In that one I'm pretty sure the kid does kill the protagonist in the original. It's from 2019 - is that too late?

Comment: @qazmlpok - What property are you referring to?

Comment: @Valorum That is The Tyrant's Sister. I started typing up an answer but the differences are even more than I remembered. 1. From 2019 2. Brother/sister 3. Brother doesn't kill her, they just both get executed together 4. The brother is briefly the hero of the story, but this is retconned by the in-universe author 5. The FL doesn't try to be nice to him at all. That said, I also haven't found any better matches.